# Google Cloud Functions Public URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How to set public route to HTTP GCF?
So, currently the default path something like this.

https://us-central1-poised-breaker-162819.cloudfunctions.net/function-1

But I want to use it in this way

https://myfunction.com

or

https://myfunction.com/thisroute

So actually it is the question of namespacing or even proxying of the requests to appropriate function. How this can be achieved?

**Update 1**

It seems, like we can use an Endpoints service for that. But it still unclear would it work with GCF or not.

Comment: I don't believe this is able to be done in Google's cloud platform - as you will need some sort of API gateway to turn your custom routes into hitting Cloud function routes similar to AWS's API gateway and Lamba. You could consider building one for your services?

Comment: @Rynak, do you mean that Google Cloud doesn't provide such feature as a service? Current solution is to run separate VM with nginx working as a proxy. I just don't know is it a good solution in terms of Google Cloud.

Comment: Yeah it's not the best solution but Google is currently playing catch up against the likes of AWS which offer the API gateway as a service.

Comment: @Ryank API Gateway costs quite a bit (much higher than the cost of running the functions itself), and the only way to invoke a lambda function via http is to use it. In contrast, Google Functions triggered by http automatically provisions a https endpoint for you to use without any added cost. However if you still want to proxy the url, maybe check out Cloud Endpoints or App Engine or something else.

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer One way I can think of is to use Google App Engine (you can set up a custom domain and import your own TLS cert or just use the appspot.com url that is provisioned automatically) and use it to route the request to the cloud function. If you use this method, you can probably invoke the function via pub/sub instead of http also.

Comment: Potentially relevant alternative (you don't need firebase) http://abe.ghost.io/using-a-custom-domain-with-google-cloud-functions-for-firebase/

Comment: @KevinLee, we deployed additional nginx service that is mapped to our resources (static content, functions, user's files) and that is using our domain.

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Endpoints acts as an API gateway for cloud functions.

For Cloud function https://[CLOUD_FUNCTION_REGION].cloudfunctions.net/my-function,

1. Set project id in Cloud shell

   ```
   gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
   ```
2. Deploy ESPv2 Beta to Cloud Run. Replace **CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME** with the name that you want to use for the service.

   ```
   gcloud run deploy CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
      --image="gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2" \
      --allow-unauthenticated \
      --platform managed
   ```

   At the end of command execution, it will have similar details as below

   > Service [CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME] revision
   >   [CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME-00001-ces] has been deployed and is serving
   >   100 percent of traffic at
   >   **https://CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME-65zrpjcu3q-uk.a.run.app**

   Note host-name receive from the above command (**CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME-65zrpjcu3q-uk.a.run.app**)
3. Create YAML file api.yaml with [OpenAPI](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/glossary#open_api_doc) spec config:

   ```yaml
     swagger: '2.0'
     info:
       title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
       description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
       version: 1.0.0
     host: CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME-65zrpjcu3q-uk.a.run.app
     schemes:
       - https
     produces:
       - application/json
     paths:
       /thisroute:
         get:
           summary: Custom function route
           x-google-backend:
             address: https://[CLOUD_FUNCTION_REGION].cloudfunctions.net/my-function
           responses:
             '200':
               description: A successful response
               schema:
                 type: string
   ```
4. Deploy Endpoint configuration:

   ```
   gcloud endpoints services deploy api.yaml
   ```
5. Now, Cloud function request can route through endpoint https://CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME-65zrpjcu3q-uk.a.run.app/thisroute.
6. Also to use custom domain name, need to verifying a domain name. For
   that follow steps from [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/serving-apis-from-domains)

Comment: It seems the API YAML now needs an `operationId` entry.  I don't fully understand the docs but the API deployed when I created one in the `get:` section

Answer (score 2):

If you use firebase functions, which are almost the same, you can do it! https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: No, I don't use firebase.

Comment: If you want to get this done, that is the way to go on GCP for the moment

Comment: Can't find if I left answer here, but we left with the separate Compute Engine and nginx proxy server which is responsible for the routes resolution.

Comment: Get it, any reason why you didnt go for appengine to proxy requests? speed?

Comment: Compute Engine looked like much simplier solution. App Engine much more finished thing and allow proxy requests with custom code, via express, or python module, but it would less performant, than nginx anyway, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at the moment. You'll need an api proxy and I honestly don't recommend exposing the public url.

In my mind the most elegant solution at this point would be creating your simple proxy application based on cloud pub/sub, you can make it run on gap, gke or the new cloud run, in order for you to scale to 0.

The logic can be dynamic and as follow:

- read the url of the request with some internal logic
- use the path of the url to choose a topic
- forward the payload to the cloud function via the pub/sub topic

however at this point you should ask yourself if this is really useful in contrast of having your application running on gae / gke, with maybe different service to split concerns, because cost-wise in can be less expensive.

If you want a SaaS solution for your "api gateway" problem, you could also look at [Apigee](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/extensions/google-cloud-functions/google-cloud-functions-extension-105)

Answer (score 1):

I think better not to use the HTTP invoke mechanism since it's doesn't require any of the authentication to invoke.
Try using other options instead -- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup Cloud Load Balancing and secure it with Cloud Amor. And then setup ingress settings on your cloud functions to accept only internal traffic and cloud load balancing.